# Identities of the form $397612 = 3^2+9^1+7^6+6^7+1^9+2^3$

Tags: number-theory

Consider the interesting equality:

$$397612 = 3^2+9^1+7^6+6^7+1^9+2^3$$

Is there any criterion for an integer number $\displaystyle m$ to satisfy the equality 
$$m=a_1+a_2\times 10^1+...+a_{n-1}\times 10^{n-2}+a_{n}\times 10^{n-1}=a_1^{a_n}+\cdots+a_{n}^{a_1}\quad?$$ 
We assume that $0 \leq a_i \leq 9$ for every $1 \leq i \leq n$ and that $a_n \geq 1$.

Comment: Maybe. Why?$\phantom{}$

Comment: There can at most be finitely many such numbers: If the number has $n$ digits then the right hand side is $\le 9^9 n$ and the left is $\ge 10^{n-1}$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen 's observation implies that the equality is impossible for $n\geq 12$.

Comment: ________________48625               ?

Comment: You should specify a convention for dealing with cases when the right hand side has terms of the form $0^0$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A quick Java program reveals the numbers:

- $1$
- $48625$
- $397612$

are the only such numbers which are less than $10^8$. This is not by any means a full answer, but it's a good start. This took a couple minutes to run, so using it to check for higher powers of $n$ isn't viable. Let me know if you have improvements for the code.

My code is below.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
class WeirdNumberTest
{
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    for (int number = 1; number < 100000000; number++)
    {
      int[] digits = getDigits(number);
      int sum = 0;
      int n = digits.length;
      for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
      {
        sum += Math.pow(digits[i], digits[n-1-i]);
      }
      if (number == sum) System.out.println(sum);
    }
  }

  public static int[] getDigits(int n)
  {
    int nbrDigits = 0;
    int currentNbr = n;
    while (currentNbr != 0)
    {
      currentNbr = currentNbr/10;
      nbrDigits++;
    }
    int[] digitArray = new int[nbrDigits];
    currentNbr = n;
    for (int i = 0; i < nbrDigits; i++)
    {
      digitArray[i] = currentNbr%10;
      currentNbr = currentNbr/10;
    }
    return digitArray;
  }
}
```

Comment: Edit: updated to having checked for $10^8$ and taking note of the time required.

Comment: the function that gives the result is not defined for every $n$
for instance if $n=1001$ the result is indeterminate because of the zeros

Comment: @Raffaele good point. Java's Math library assumes by default that $0^0 = 1$. However, we may as well just ignore these cases, since they don't have much meaning.

Comment: It's impossible to have such numbers higher than $L\approx 3.5\times 10^9$ because the sum of the powers becomes smaller than the number itself

Comment: That's a pretty good estimate; much better than the $10^{12}$ from the comment on the question. How'd you get it, exactly?

Comment: It's impossible to have such numbers higher than $L\approx 3\times 10^9$ because the sum of the powers becomes smaller than the number itself. For $10^{10} - 1$ the result is $3\,874\,204\,890$ and obviously for greater numbers the result is even smaller than the number itself for $10^{11}-1$ its just $10\%$ more than the number with ten $9$s

Answer (score 2):

Not quite the same form, but I like $2^59^2 = 2592$.

Comment: And apparently someone doesn't (delete vote).  Oh well.